# Rails - How can I run cucumber tests only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, cucumber, rake

I can run all models with `rake:models`

Any option to do that that for cucumber tests instead of just `rake` and running all tests at all levels?

I tried:

```
$ rake spec:cucumber
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'spec:cucumber'
```

Comment: @janders223 has the right answer. Just to clarify, Rspec has nothing to do with Cucumber, that's why there's no such thing as `rake spec:cucumber`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to just run `rake cucumber`

A quick output of `rake -T` shows:

```
rake cucumber                          # Alias for cucumber:ok
rake cucumber:all                      # Run all features
rake cucumber:ok                       # Run features that should pass
rake cucumber:rerun                    # Record failing features and run only them if any exist
rake cucumber:wip                      # Run features that are being worked on
```

Comment: Just to add, you can also just use the `cucumber` script without rake.

Comment: Very true, and also it is possible to run `rake cucumber:ok spec`  to run all features and specs together.